# Automate the creation of converters or other generic solution

Tags: wpf, xaml

When i need to display an enumeration in a View, i write a converter for this type of enumeration

For Example:

```
Public Enum ReportTypes
    Overview
    Crosstable
    AllCPDetails
End Enum
```

My converter is:

```
Public Class ReportTypeToStringConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Property Overview As String
    Public Property Crosstable As String
    Public Property AllCPDetails As String

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim enumValue As ReportTypes = DirectCast(value, ReportTypes)
        Select Case enumValue
            Case ReportTypes.Overview
                Return Overview
            Case ReportTypes.Crosstable
                Return Crosstable
            Case ReportTypes.AllCPDetails
                Return AllCPDetails
            Case Else
                Return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue
        End Select
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

then, in my XAML i can write this:

```
<local:ReportTypeToStringConverter x:Key="ReportTypeToStringConverter"
                                   Overview="Overview"
                                   Crosstable="Cross Table"
                                   AllCPDetails="All CP Details"/>
```

In this example there is an relationship of "Enum <--> String", but i can need write another relationships: "Enum <--> Color", "Enum <--> Visibility"....

The code is very clean and all work ok, but when i have many enums, or many relationships... How can i automatice the converter creation? Snippets? Item Template in Visual Studio?

Another generic solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probably most generic converter could use a ResourceDictionary to map from the a value's `ToString()` result to an arbitrary object. The source value does not even need to be an enum.

```
public class GenericConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private readonly ResourceDictionary resources = new ResourceDictionary();

    public ResourceDictionary Resources
    {
        get { return resources; }
    }

    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return resources[value.ToString()];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You would e.g. use it like this to convert Visibility values:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:GenericConverter x:Key="VisibilityToSomeStringConverter">
        <local:GenericConverter.Resources>
            <sys:String x:Key="Visible">VISIBLE</sys:String>
            <sys:String x:Key="Hidden">HIDDEN</sys:String>
            <sys:String x:Key="Collapsed">COLLAPSED</sys:String>
        </local:GenericConverter.Resources>
    </local:GenericConverter>
    <local:GenericConverter x:Key="VisibilityToSomeIntConverter">
        <local:GenericConverter.Resources>
            <sys:Int32 x:Key="Visible">10</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32 x:Key="Hidden">20</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32 x:Key="Collapsed">30</sys:Int32>
        </local:GenericConverter.Resources>
    </local:GenericConverter>
</Window.Resources>
```